# Use this function if nonlinear expression in vector

Tags: types, julia, multiple-dispatch

I have a vector `a` that can contain several different types of elements of the expressions  `QuadExpr, NonlinearExpression, AffExpr, VariableRef`. However, I want that if one of the elements (expressions) in `a` is a `NonlinearExpression` or a `QuadExpression` this function should be used:

```
function add_pen!(pen, model::JuMP.Model, a::Union{Vector{QuadExpr}, Vector{NonlinearExpression}}, b, i,len) 
    
        pen[i] = @NLexpression(model, sum(a[j] * b[j] for j in 1:len)); 
    end
```

If `a` contains neither `NonlinearExpression` nor  `QuadExpression` this function should be used:

```
function add_pen!(pen, model::JuMP.Model, a, b, i,len) 
    
        pen[i] = @expression(model, sum(a[j] * b[j] for j in 1:len)); 
    end
```

I know this will not work as `a::Union{Vector{QuadExpr}, Vector{NonlinearExpression}}` means that `a` is either a Vector of only `QuadExpression` or `NonlinearExpressions`. Is it possible to use multiple-dispatch functions in this case or do I need to use the if and else statements instead? Like,

```
if any(x -> typeof(x) == NonlinearExpression, a)
   pen[i] = @NLexpression ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dispatch on types of `varargs`.
I will make the example code without `JuMP` so it is easier to replicate (you can of  course change to your JuMP types).

Consider the following two types:

```
TypesA = Union{Int,Float64,Rational{Int}}
TypesB = Union{TypesA,String,Char}
```

You can define the following functions:

```
g(a::TypesA...) = println("running A")
g(a::TypesB...) = println("running B")
```

Now let us test it:

```
julia> g([1,2,3//4]...)
running A

julia> g([1,2,3//4,"hello"]...)
running B
```

You can see that `varags` makes it possible to dispatch on the various combination of `Vector` elements.
Note that this works correctly regardless the fact the the type of elements of `Vector` above is `Any`:

```
julia> eltype([1,2,3//4,"hello"])
Any
```

In your `add_pen!` you will need to move `a` to the end to be the last parameter.

Comment: Thank you, but what about the case where I want both `a` and `b` to be checked like; `g(a::TypesA,b::TypesB)`?

Comment: Or this case: `g(a::TypesB...,b) = println(b)
  
g(a,b::TypesB...) = println(a) `?

Comment: I could perhaps add them in the same vector and then separate them inside the function like, `function g(ab::TypesA...)  length(ab)/2; 
    a = ab[1:n/2]
    b = ab[n/2 + 1:end] do... end` Maybe not the most elegant way

Comment: Still one problem though since I want to distinguish between a being a vector and a being a single expression etc.

Comment: You will not be able to distinguish between ` g(a::TypesB...,b) ` and  `g(b, a::TypesB...)`. Basically you want vararg `a::TypesB...` to always be the last parameter of the function.

Comment: An ugly solution would be ` h(a1::NTuple{N1, TypesA}, a2::NTuple{N2, TypesB}) where {N1,N2}= println("ab")` and then you could do `h(([1,2,3]...,),(["a",1]...,))`